# Creating contact form with bottom bordered elements

Tags: html, css

I'm aiming to create a contact form where all of the inputs are the same width and are only underlined with a gradient. The `textarea` shouldn't be able to resize larger than the width of the rest of the inputs. I'm not sure if simulating the underline would work best if this can't be achieved.

```css
::placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

input[type= name], select {
  width: 50 % ;
  padding: 15 px;
  margin: 3.75 px;
  display: inline - block;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border - bottom: linear-gradient(50 deg, #006699, #9900CC);
}

input[type= email], select {
  width: 50 % ;
  padding: 15 px;
  margin: 3.75 px;
  display: inline - block;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border - bottom: linear-gradient(50 deg, #006699, #9900CC);
}

input[type= textarea], select {
  width: 50 % ;
  padding: 15 px;
  margin: 3.75 px;
  display: inline - block;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border - bottom: linear-gradient(50 deg, #006699, #9900CC);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="action" action="action" autocomplete="off"> <br>
   <input type="name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" required> <br>
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required=> <br>
   <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" cols="20" placeholder="Compose a message." required></textarea>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" required="">
</form>
```

Here's a mockup of what I'm aiming for because I don't know how else to approach this. I'm using placeholders instead of labels for ease.

[image: Mockup]

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to achieve. Apologies for there not being as much code close to something working, I have no idea how to approach this so I've had to give an overview of the problem and as much as I'm able to try.

`UPDATE`
I initially had no idea how to do this for the `<textarea>` so the current answer has been helpful for that aspect of it. Below is a workaround.

I've placed it on a black background to make everything easier to visualise in contrast. There's an issue with the text inputs being a different width to the textarea so this will need to be fixed too. Using DIVs for those underlines like this is the best workaround I can think of presently.

```css
body, html {
  background: black;
}

input[type=name],
input[type=email] {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 3.75px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}

textarea {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 3.75px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 5px transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}

.input-underline {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 3.75px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="action" action="action" autocomplete="off"> <br>
  <input type="name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" required> <br>
  <div class="input-underline"></div>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required=> <br>
  <div class="input-underline"></div>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" cols="20" placeholder="Compose a message." required></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" required="">
</form>
```

`FURTHER UPDATE`
Here's some more progress that gets the desired result.

```css
body,
html {
  background: black;
}

input[type=name],
input[type=email] {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

textarea {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 5px transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}

.input-underline {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="action" action="action" autocomplete="off">
   <br>
   <input type="name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" required> <br>
   <div class="input-underline"></div>
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required=> <br>
   <div class="input-underline"></div>
   <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" cols="20" placeholder="Compose a message." required></textarea>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" required="">
</form>
```

Image added because stacksnippets doesn't show the output correctly.
[image: Example image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some weird selectors and spaces in your CSS! But with some cleanup and a `background` element for the name and email inputs. For the `textarea` it was a bit harder, but with a `border-image` it could be done!

```css
.border-bottom {
  width: 50%;
  height: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #006699, #9900CC);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input[type=name],
input[type=email] {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}

textarea {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 3.75px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 5px transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="action" action="action" autocomplete="off"> <br>
  <input type="name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" required>
  <div class="border-bottom"></div>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <div class="border-bottom"></div>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" cols="20" placeholder="Compose a message." required></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" required="">
</form>
```

Comment: I've just played about with it and it's incredibly close. I can't believe I didn't notice I'd put CSS in the wrong place. The one thing I would like is to have a border radius so that the lines and the box are curved, if this is possible?

Comment: Ideally all of them. Usually `border-radius: 10px;` would work but it doesn't round the edges.

Comment: @learningtoanimate, I've updated my answer! I'm still doing research on the name and email input border, but I'm afraid it isn't possible! I was able to add a `border-radius` to the bottom of the border. I will continue my research! If I find anything else I will comment right here!

Comment: I'm still looking too. I had considered having just the placeholder and then a DIV below each element as a workaround. The issue is that the border radius affects the whole input and not the bottom border, that's why.

Comment: Exactly, I hope it does fulfill your need even though it isn't exactly what you want! I will continue to search for a solution!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215257/discussion-between-learningtoanimate-and-meesegberts).

Comment: Accepted answer based on the approach to `<textarea>`. The final answer copied the second update in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example with a radius for the inputs to show what's going on. Thanks to [MeesEgberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10791031/meesegberts) for their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62179494/12007347).

This answer matches the second update as I found that approach to be the best overall.

```css
body,
html {
  background: black;
}

input[type=name],
input[type=email] {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

textarea {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 5px transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}

.input-underline {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #006699, #9900CC);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="action" action="action" autocomplete="off"> <br>
  <input type="name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" required> <br>
  <div class="input-underline"></div>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required=> <br>
  <div class="input-underline"></div>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" cols="20" placeholder="Compose a message." required></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" required="">
</form>
```